# move_uploaded_file() not working as expected (i.e at all) in PHP

Tags: php, http, file-upload

using this line

```
$file_move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'],
                                plugins_url('/css', __FILE__));
```

returns:

> move_uploaded_file(http://localhost/*******) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/*********/as_settings.php on line 60

I have checked both arguments, and they are correct. I'm new to this side of coding, what have I missed?

---EDIT

In response to answers, have changed code to:

```
$dir = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/app-switcher/css';
$file = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
$file_move = move_uploaded_file($file,$dir);
```

Now my error response is:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs//wp-content/plugins/app-switcher/css/) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Is a directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs//wp-content/plugins/app-switcher/as_settings.php on line 61

Comment: you also need $dest_file (destination filename) and use $file_move = move_uploaded_file($file,$dir.'/'.$destfile); or define the whole path + filename in one variable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error message is pretty obvious, your destination file should be a path, not a URL

Comment: Yes, and since uploaded files always have temporay names (usually something like /tmp/pmYouIo8z), it's obvious you need to rename it, hence the destination being a full path to the destination *file* name.

Comment: @Mild you need to specify a full path, including the file name. http://php.net/move_uploaded_file

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a `http://` URL as the target for `move_uploaded_file()`. You need to use a file path.

You're not saying what framework you are using, but it may have a counterpart to  `plugins_url()` that returns a file path.

Comment: using wordpress, have changed it, and edited my question in response

Answer (score 0):

second parameter should not be URL

Answer (score 0):

It's still obvious.
you have to pass a filename, not directory to this function